# iOS - Dropbox API : How to have a UIProgressView which displays the average value of datas sended to Dropbox?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, progress-bar, dropbox-api

I use Dropbox API, and I have a UIProgressView.

When I put multiple files to Dropbox, the method I use is called for all of these files and so my progressView displays incoherent values (5%, 7%, 3%, etc...) because it displays the download value of each file separately.

I use this method :

```
    func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadProgress progress: CGFloat, forFile destPath: String!, from srcPath: String!) {        
    self.progressBar.progress = Float(progress)
}
```

And so, if I put 4 files, this method is called for the 4 files, and my progressBar displays incoherent values.

Is there a solution, a method or a property to set for example to display the correct progression ?

When my 4 files are uploaded, I want my progressBar to display 100%.

When I have 40%, 30%, 50%, 30% for my 4 files, I want my progressBar to display 37.5%

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, store your progress in distinct variables, average them, and set your progressBar with the result. Instead of directly setting the progress of the bar, store an array of values. After you change a value, you can call an "update" function that would simply average your array values, and set the result to your progress meter